# PowerPivot LOOKUPVALUE

Tags: filter, powerpivot, dax

I'd appreciate any pointers on this, I need to look up in PP a value based on a range in another PP Table.

I want to return 'BAND' based on where Revenue in the first table falls between High and Low Band Values in the Band Table.

```
=LOOKUPVALUE(Band[Band],Band[Low],>=[Revenue],Band[High],<=[Revenue])
```

The Band Table is set up as

```
Band 0-100 Low 0 High 100
Band 101-200 Low 101 High 200
etc
```

I've also tried this...

```
=FILTER(Band[Band],[Revenue]>=Band[Low],[Revenue]<=Band[High])
```

Thanks for your help.
Gav

Comment: Is Revenue a measure or a column? What is the Band[Band] column data type?

Comment: Hi, Revenue is a column in the first table called combined, it is a numerical value. Band[Band] is a Text column, such as '0-100   '101-200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LookupValue doesn't support conditional evaluations, instead you can use a `FILTER` function and `FIRSTNONBLANK` function to get the right `Band[Band]`.

Create a calculated column in the `Combined` table using this expression:

```
LookupBand =
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( Band[Band], 0 ),
    FILTER (
        Band,
        [Low] <= EARLIER ( Combined[Revenue] )
            && [High] >= EARLIER ( Combined[Revenue] )
    )
)
```

Comment: @Gavin, you are welcome, if my answer solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.